# Unable to open the pages in Ionic App via links from mail

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I have created the Ionic in-app browser app, and installed it on an Android phone. Now when I try to click on the links from the mail, it has to open the app and navigate to that particular page.

I used the intent filters in the AndroidMainfest.xml and now when I click on the links from the mail, it is opening the app but is not navigating to the page the link is directing to. Can someone help me with this issue?

[image]

[image: Deeplink Image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Deeplink plugin for setting the routes and the actions!

```
this.deeplinks.route({
     '/about-us': AboutPage,
     '/universal-links-test': AboutPage,
     '/products/:productId': ProductPage
   }).subscribe(match => {
     // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
     // match.$args - the args passed in the link
     // match.$link - the full link data
     console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
   }, nomatch => {
     // nomatch.$link - the full link data
     console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
   });
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks

Comment: I wanted to use the Intent-filter alone.

Comment: I think that intent-filter on manifest is for the "android side" of your app. But the js navigation is "like a browser". So you need to bind the sides with deeplink!

Comment: Do you have any sample code?

Comment: This is the code I wrote and still the flow is not working.

Comment: I have added the deeplink code as well, can you kindly check and provide some info on why it is not working.

Comment: @VikramSaiSimha errors? It pass from .subscribe() ? What doesn't work?